# combine multiple functions with same code in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Yes, I have thoroughly searched google and did not find anything that suits my requirement.

The code i have so far is at the link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKwTY/4/

There are multiple onchange events which call almost the same code, i would like to combine them maybe in a comma separated fashion to call it only once.
  something like this

```
   (on1Change, on2Change, on3Change): function () {
       this.loadData();
     }
```

is this possible??

Note: these functions are bound to the controls via a framework over which i do not have control, i need to create these functions and the framework would bind these to the respective controls

Comment: if all are doing the same then why don't you make just one function and call tthat instead... `onChange:function(){ this.loadData(); }` and call it whereever you want... instead of creating `on1Change , on2Change.....`

Comment: these functions are bound to the controls via a framework over which i do not have control, i need to create these function and the framework would bind these to the respective controls..  plz have a look at the link http://jsfiddle.net/ZKwTY/4/

Answer (score 1):

or you can create your object like this

```
var ol = {
on1Change: this.loadData,
on2Change: this.loadData,
on3Change: this.loadData,
on4Change: this.loadData,

loadData: function () {
    this.loadData1();
    this.loadData2();
},

loadData1: function () {
    alert('hi from loadData1');
},

loadData2: function () {
    alert('hi from loadData2');
}
};
```

Then if you want to do it once, then declare a object

```
var ol = {
    loadData: function () {
        this.loadData1();
        this.loadData2();
    },

    loadData1: function () {
        alert('hi from loadData1');
    },

    loadData2: function () {
        alert('hi from loadData2');
    }
};// end of object

ol.on1Change = ol.on2Change = ol.on3Change = ol.on4Change = ol.loadData;
```

add all propteries dynamically after object declaration

Comment: ur close.. but instead of

        
**********************

         on1Change: this.loadData,
        on2Change: this.loadData,
        on3Change: this.loadData,
        on4Change: this.loadData,

**********************

can we have something like
**********
 on1Change,on2Change,on3Change,on4Change: this.loadData,
**************

bcoz we are having the call to this.loadData 4 times.. i would prefer to have it only once...

note: there are 12 onchange functions in my code which point to this.loadData

Comment: The previous code will work which is the second choice.

Answer (score 0):

use **[bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)**

```
$("selector").bind(on1Change, on2Change, on3Change): function () {
        this.loadData();
  }.....
```

Comment: thanks Rituraj, but i do not have any selector, these are callbacks created by a framework over which i do not have control, if you look at the code here http://jsfiddle.net/ZKwTY/4/ you would be able to understand more

Answer (score 0):

you can try somethig like this http://jsfiddle.net/s4VVY/
i.e. add methods after object create

```
[1,2,3,4,5].forEach(function(it){ol["on"+it+"Change"] = function(){this.loadData()}})
```

**UPDATE**
may be this help

```
var ol = (function(){
    var o = {
        loadData: function () {
            this.loadData1();
            this.loadData2();
        },

        loadData1: function () {
            alert('hi from loadData1');
        },

        loadData2: function () {
            alert('hi from loadData2');
        }
    }
    o.on1Change=o.on2Change=o.on3Change=o.on4Change=function(){ this.loadData();};

    return o;
})()
```

also you can make function bindFunc

```
function bindFunc(){
    var obj = arguments[0],
        handler = arguments[1],
        properties = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,2);

    for(var i in properties){
        obj[properties[i]] = handler;
    }
}
```

and call as

```
bindFunc(o,function(){this.loadData();},"on1Change","on2Change","on3Change","on4Change")
```

Comment: thanks Grundy.... but this is how the framework is assigning the functions to the controls, i cannot touch the framework code, thereby i hav to create those functions , but would like to remove the repetitive code and just write the function call once..

Comment: in your sample `ol` object it's a framework object? if no then when you add properties you don't touch framework code

Comment: ol is not a framework object, its a local object, the framework takes a list of controls, populates the data and creates the callback function which will point to the function that are listed here.. so 1,2,3,4.. will be the controls, and the callback functions would be created as on1change, on2change etc.. most of these function will have almost the same code, while a couple will have different logic within them.. so i want to combine the callbacks which hav the same code in just 1 line.. for e.g. 

on1Change,on2Change,on3Change,on4Change: this.loadData

Comment: ol.on1Change=ol.on2Change=ol.on3Change=ol.on4Change = ol.loadData - is code in just 1 line